# D3v6 drag event callback function fire with undefined parameters

Tags: d3.js, events, parameters, callback, draggable

Following the D3v6 documentation, i am unable to implement a simple dragging behaviour on a path SVG element drawn using the d3.symbol util. The typescript class is shown here as a context.
The events trigger on the correct element but the callback functions do not seem to receive the (event, datum) parameters.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default class Sliders {
    svg: SVGSVGElement;

    constructor(svg: SVGSVGElement){
        this.svg = svg;
    }

    draw(){
        const g = d3.select(this.svg).append('g').attr('class', 'symbol');   
        const circle = g.append('circle').attr('r', 200);

        const D = d3.drag() // `event` and `d` are always undefined in 3 lines below
            .on("start", (event, d) => circle.attr("stroke", "lime"))
            .on("drag", (event, d: any) => (d.x = event.x, d.y = event.y))
            .on("end", (event, d) => circle.attr("stroke", "black")) as any; // Could not fathom the proper type
        circle.call(D); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible cause for the issue is that the `d3` version used in the first example is not v6.0. There was a significant change from v5.x to v6.0 [where the event is no longer a global variable but passed as a parameter in callbacks](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide).

Your code is in v6.0 style, so it works in the second example, where it is explicitly importing v6.0 from https://d3js.org/

You can confirm if your original code is running d3 v6.0 with a `console.log(d3.event)` inside one of the callbacks:

```js
  .on("drag", () => { 
    console.log(d3.event);
  })
```

If the code above logs the event, it means your d3 is in version v5.x.
If it works, but typescript also gives a type error anyway, it means that your typings (`@types/d3`) are for v6.0, so they are not aligned with the installed version of d3.

In any case, if `d3.event` works, then the easiest solution is to update your d3 to v6.0 since you already have the code compatible with the latest version.

The second parameter of the callback is the datum bound to the element. In your example, it is expected to be `undefined` because there is no datum associated with the circle (i.e., there is no `.selectAll(...).data(...)` before the `.append()`). If interested, you could check [a d3-drag example in v.6.0 that uses data binding](https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-dragging-i) to understand it better.

So, a minimal drag behavior example in v5.0, without data binding, would be:

```js
 .on("drag", function() { 
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d3.event.x).attr("cy", d3.event.y);
  })
```

And in v6.0:

```js
 .on("drag", function(event) { 
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", event.x).attr("cy", event.y);
  })
```

Node: Remember to use the `function` keyword instead of an arrow function (`() => ...`) [if you want acess to the correct `this` object inside it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
Turns out my setup was using d3v6 typings but probably had a d3v5.X module installed.
`npm install d3@\^6`
set things straight, event and d parameters are now defined.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself for some details.
Striping any webpack/typescript business,
In a single html file, drag event callback parameters are defined

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<div id="data"> </div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script>
const svg = d3.select('#data').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);
console.log(svg);
const circle = svg.append('circle').attr('r', 5).attr('cy', 25).attr('cx', 25);
// `event` parameter is defined
const D = d3.drag()
            .on("start", (event, d) => circle.attr("stroke", "lime"))
            .on("drag", (event, d) => { 
                  console.log(event);
            })  
            .on("end", (event, d) => circle.attr("stroke", "black")); 
circle.call(D); 
    
</script>
```

Does not solve my initial problem, though.